# Excel 2013: Concatenate 2 names in name manager

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, validation

I use data validation to create dropdowns in two cells.
The dropdowns contain data of names in the name manager.
I need to create an other name in the name manager who contains the concatenation of two first (format: name1 + ' - ' + name2) in order to apply it in an other dropdown. How to do that ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - Create a third column in your excel sheet that concatenates the Columns for you and use this as the source in your name manager range.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is good but I would a solution to concatenate two sources in one from the name manager without using an other column.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using '&' in the source formula in name manager.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking Name Manager

1. Select New
2. Give it a name (i.e., concatenateLatLon)
3. In the *Refers to:* enter formula

For example, if I wanted to concatenate data from Column A, Latitude, with Column B, Longitude, in Sheet1, AND have a comma that separates the two, I would use the below formula in the *Refers to:* field

=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A2)&(", ")&(Sheet1!B2)

[concatenate example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4NsO.png)